# Using Synergy with PC that has Wireless Keyboard and Mouse

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, keyboard, mouse, synergy

I'm trying to have my PC with wireless keyboard and mouse as the server.

It works if the wireless PC is the client and the wired PC is the server, but I need it the opposite way. Is there a way to do this? I hope so, and will keep looking for a different solution, though I hope to get an answer to this question.

Synergy is a fantastic app, either way, I'm amazed at the ease with which it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no difference between using any one PC for the server and using any other.

Things you have to be wary of though:

1. Ensure the firewall on the machine you want to be the server allows clients to connect to synergy through it.
2. Ensure that the IP address of the server machine is both known and, ideally, static.